# Calculating expected value from definition. Where is the mistake?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Probability density function $f(x)$ for continous random variable has following property:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx=1$$

Expected value $EX$ is given as:
$$EX=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx$$

So I tried to perform integration in definition of $EX$ by parts for $u(x)=x$, $v'(x)=f(x)$:

$$EX=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx = {[x]}_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^\infty1(x)dx$$

Did I violate some rules of integration or just came in a legit way to situation which is meaningless due to subtraction of indefinite values?

Comment: No! Your way is total wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg can you please explain a bit?

Comment: You can not use $x|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ because it's an absurd.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you. I do realize it won't help me with anything, but is the way I obtained it also incorrect?

Comment: I think we need something more about $f$.

Comment: I don't understand where the $v$ went or what the $1(x)$ inside the integral is. The integration by parts formula should be $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx = \left.xv(x)\right|_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty v(x)dx.$$ (Which is not to say that it's useful here.. $v(\infty)=1$ so things diverge)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Wouldn't the property of $f(x)$ I quoted imply $v(x)$ being $1$?

Comment: @SzymonBrych No, not at all. It implies $v(\infty)-v(-\infty) = 1.$ The most famous thing whose derivative is the PDF is the CDF (i.e. $v(x)$ will be the CDF plus an arbitrary constant).

Comment: @SzymonBrych what you have given in property is definite integral of $f(x)$ but $v(x)$ is not a definite integral.

Comment: Saying that one "can not use $\left.x\right|_{-\infty}^\infty$ because it's an absurd" is (ungrammatical and) about as useful as horseshoes to practice windsurfing. After all, it could happen that the integral is undefined - and in some cases it is. Fortunately, user @spacedarkgreen hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it wrong in integration by parts.

Actually, 
$$EX=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx = {[x v(x)]}_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^\infty v(x)dx$$ where $v(x) = \int f(x) dx $.